# How to find the most common n elements in groups of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have a db with ~30K properties.  Each property has anywhere from 1 to 200 tenants (about 100K tenants).  I am looking to find the most common grouping of n tenants (where n is generally 3, 4 or 5).

Say n = 3.

```
Property 1 -<br> 
 Tenants - A, B, C, D, E<br> 
Property 2 - <br> 
 Tenants - A, D, E, F, G<br> 
Property 3 - <br> 
 Tenants - A, B, G, H, I<br> 
Property 4 - <br> 
 Tenants - A, J, K, L, M<br>
```

In this case, even though A has 4 occurrences, the most frequent count of 3 common elements is 2 instances of A, D, E in properties 1 and 2.

I don't know where to start to set this up as a re-usable algorithm.  Can someone, much smarter than I, please point me in the right direction?  Many thanks.

Comment: This is a version of the [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) which is np-complete. I would start looking there but keep in mind, especially with numbers as large as you have, the time it takes to find the exact solution may be unreasonably high.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database defines a many-to-many relationship between properties and tenants, you can self-join the relation table to get that result. Here's an example with n=3.

```sql
SELECT p1.tenant, p2.tenant, p3.tenant, COUNT(p1.property) occurrences
FROM property_tenants p1
JOIN property_tenants p2 ON p1.property = p2.property AND p1.tenant < p2.tenant
JOIN property_tenants p3 ON p1.property = p3.property AND p2.tenant < p3.tenant
GROUP BY p1.tenant, p2.tenant, p3.tenant
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
```

I don't really know how well this will perform with a large set of data, to be honest. I can just see that it works logically.